# PHP ObjectStorag on Deis

Tags: php, ceph, deis

So, i've installed deis onto HyperV with three nodes. This is working as it should :). The applications that will be running on DEIS are PHP Applications and are Private applications, so no Public cloud services :(.

The App has three dependencies: Memcached (caching), MySql (Data, Session Storage) and File Storage.  What are the best practices to run such an app? I would like to keep everything within these three nodes. Memcached is not the issue, just spin up some docker containers. MySQL could live on a separate server.

While trying to change the app to the 12Factor way i would like to use Object Storage for the uploaded files. S3 is not a option, and containers have no persistent storage. Which leaves another server or using the components already available.

I've noticed port 8888 is opened on the nodes, doing a Curl gives me an XML with "ListAllMyBucketsResult" Which is the respons from the Ceph Rados GW. Is there a way to add an user for the application and using this for object storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Ceph gateway, you should create a new user account for it. Do this by entering the `deis-store-gateway` container with `nse deis-store-gateway` on the host the container runs on. You can then use `radosgw-admin`: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/admin/

Comment: Ok, so would you think this is the way to go? or would i have to deploy something like minio or swift somewhere?